# Saber url externa con la que ingresaron a mi app?

Tags: angular, typescript

Necesito saber desde que url externa ingresaron a cierta url de mi aplicacion supongamos yo estoy en facebook.com e ingreso a localhost/login, bueno como hago para saber que venian desde facebook?

Osea, yo tengo en mi frontend una url que acepta queryparams.. ahora a esta url solo puedo aceptar que me envien estos queryparams de una url externa especifica. para este ejemplo supongamos que se llama pepito.com ,solo pepito.com puede enviarme eso.

Entonces yo necesito validar que la url que accede a mi ruta en front sea pepito.com

Lo que es **document.referrer**: No me sirvio, solo de forma "interna" y cada tanto no andaba, de forma externa que es lo que necesito no me sirvio. **(Osea cuando hago un console log me lo devuelve vacio)**

El **objeto history** no tiene alguna propiedad que me devuelva la url
El **objeto location**, no sirve para cuando es externa, si fuese ruta interna si.

Y en angular no se si hay algo, en el **routeActive** o algo que me de esa url, tipo un **header origin**, pero ojo, header no el que seteas para VOS hacer un request, en este caso seria el "request" que te estan haciendo a vos

Comment: Puedes agregar cuál es el propósito de querer hacer eso? quizás estás viendo el problema de forma incorrecta y  la solución deba ser otra.

Comment: Es para validar que se haga el queryparam solo de una url externa especifica, es un ticket que tengo pendiente en el trabajo

Comment: Trato de entender en qué parte se involucra Angular en eso. En mi experiencia encuentro que lo más parecido es que que el backend solo acepte peticiones desde un dominio específico. Angular directamente no es capaz de recibir peticiones porque no es un servidor HTTP solo es una app que se ejecuta en el cliente.

Comment: Y, si el visitante usa un modelo de navegación anónima (tiene derecho a hacerlo) ¿Qué harías? Adicionalmente, si lo logras: ¿no estarías violando el derecho a la privacidad de tus visitantes? Además de que en general, la info de headers que da cuenta del origen del llamado **no es confiable**, no tienes derecho a conocer el historial de navegación de tus visitantes y no creo que los lenguajes que indicas te permitan lograrlo. Sospecho que necesitarías **un mecanismo torcido** ...

Comment: @Lobos porque la ruta, no esta en el backend, es una ruta del front que acepta queryparams, la cual desde otra web cliente, pongamos de ejemplo google.com, tienen un enlace hacia mi ruta en front y me mandan los queryparams. Por eso yo en el front con angular, necesito validar que sea google.com como para llamar un servicio supongamos, y si no es google no continuo.

Comment: Pero si en otro sitio tienen la url del front en Angular al darle clic no se envía una petición a un servidor para descargar el contenido del front?

Comment: En PHP hay algo que se llama `REMOTE_ADDR` y te devuelve la ip del visitante, mas aun no se si puedas obtener la url de una redirección de google. Lo que si puedes obtener son las ip de los robots que indexen tus paginas. Esto es parecido a lo que buscas?